# Gibberish at exaption

Tags: c#

I want to see the exaption at the console , i run this progarm :

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
            try
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a index : ");
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("The number at index "+index+" is "+arr[index]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Some error : "+ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And i get this exaption :

[image]

Comment: Exception messages are typically in English, which means you're using a *localized* runtime. You wouldn't get `?` otherwise.

Comment: What i need to doing ? I tried all the possible fonts as listed in the post above, but I always get question marks. I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you use `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`?

Comment: Yes , its not do anything ...